# Jquery is Ready wrapper

Tags: javascript, jquery

is there any javascript code wrap that can be use to wait for Jquery to load and create a callback after loading jquery successfully?

something like this

```
JqueryWait(function(){
   //my magnificent jquery codes ^^
});
```

I want a code wrap something like this...

Explanation:
I'm using headjs and i loaded jquery in a separate code of headjs. now my other scripts relies on the jquery and that's why that other script must know if the jquery is already loaded. I know about the callback function of headjs but my other script can't be put on the callback function

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
function JqueryWait(fn) {
    if (jQuery) fn();
    else setTimeout(function() { JqueryWait(fn); }, 100);
}

JqueryWait(function(){
   //my magnificent jquery codes ^^
});
```

Comment: @Starx: polling seems the only way to go though, I think the OP is loading jQuery after the page is loaded. Either that or it's for a GM script

Answer (score 0):

```
$(function() {
// code jere... jquery is loaded
});
```

more info: http://api.jquery.com/ready/

Comment: Doesn't seem to be a good reason. Maybe more people know it with the .ready().

Comment: And maybe the other point is to make sure you load jquery before you invoke this, i.e the basic rules of loading and evaluating scripts.

Comment: $ is jquery and i want to know if jquery is loaded or not

Comment: I didn't downvote it, but it misses the point of the question (as do all the answers suggesting $()). The OP wants to know when **jQuery** is ready, not when the document is ready (i.e. when `$` can be called).

Answer (score 0):

As long as you put the jQuery file before your javascript file in the document (doesn't matter if you put both files into one `.js` file), jQuery should be loaded before your code starts.  Otherwise, jQuery didn't load right.  You can use this fallback method to check for jQuery in your script:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
if (typeof jQuery == 'undefined') {
    document.write(unescape("%3Cscript src='/js/jquery-1.7.2.min.js' type='text/javascript'%3E%3C/script%3E"));
}
</script>
```

via [CSS-Tricks](http://css-tricks.com/snippets/jquery/fallback-for-cdn-hosted-jquery/)

If you're looking to load jQuery *after* the page has loaded, you have two options.  Inject a script tag sourcing jQuery to the DOM and wait for document load (like the above example), or use an asynchronous loader like [RequireJS](http://requirejs.org/) (which honestly does pretty much the same thing but is nicer to use for many other purposes like dependency management).

Note: the other answers using `$(function(){})`:

That method only waits for the DOM to load, it does not check for the existence of jQuery before running code.

Comment: `$(...)` doesn't wait for anything, it's called immediately. The function passed to it is called when jQuery thinks the DOM is loaded.

Comment: It still waits for the DOM to execute that function is what I mean, compared to waiting for jQuery.

Answer (score -1):

You dont need extra function to do this. jQuery's `$(document).ready(function() { });` is enough for this.

```
$(function() {
    //ever code written inside here is run, after the jQuery & DOM is ready
});
```

Anways, there is another way to do check if jQuery has been loaded or not

```
if (typeof jQuery == 'undefined') {
   //... jquery not loaded
}
```

Comment: Please leave a comment, you are downvoting. Thank You

Comment: You missed the point of the question - if you call `$()` before jQuery is loaded (i.e. before `$` has been assigned a value) the user will get an error.

Comment: $ is jquery and i want to know if jquery is loaded or not

Comment: @Mahan, $ is not jquery, it is assigned as jquery object, once jquery is loaded.